# AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion: how to use the void* parameter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-audio

I want to play two sounds, but the last one only after the first ends.

I'm using AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion like that:

```
  NSArray  *data      = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:target, callback, nil]; 
  NSString *soundPath = [bundle pathForResource:sound ofType:type];

  SystemSoundID soundID;
  AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundPath], &soundID);
  AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion(soundID, NULL, NULL, playSoundFinished, data);

  AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

and my playSoundFinished method:

```
static void playSoundFinished(SystemSoundID soundID, void *data) {

    NSArray *data_ = (NSArray *)data;
 id  obj    = [data_ objectAtIndex:0];
 SEL method = NSSelectorFromString([data_ objectAtIndex:1]);

 [obj performSelector:method];

}
```

The documentation stats that the last parameter must be a `void*` and that it's the data to work in callback method, but how can I use the NSArray that I pass as argument? I'm new in C and Objective-C, so sorry if it's a dumb question. Casting works fine, but when I try to access the first position, a bad execution occurs. I really didn't understand why void* type. What that means?

In this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351995/error-when-trying-to-hide-a-button-from-a-sound-callback-function-when-using-audi) the guy pass a UIButton without any casting and that idea didn't work for me too.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retain your NSArray somewhere before passing it to your completion routine as a void*.  The OS can't do it because it doesn't even know if a void* is an object or not.

Comment: A void* is simple a placeholder for a pointer to an arbitrary type, e.g. anything, since the routine doesn't know or restrict what type data (object, array, dictionary, struct, int, float, frog, etc.) you want to pass.

Comment: NSArray arrayWithObjects returns a autorelease array. I think that isn't the problem.

Comment: An autorelease object isn't retained anywhere (unless you retain it or pass it to something that retains it).  Thus non-usable.

Comment: You are right. I had to pass the argument with [data copy] and release it in the callback function. Thanks very much.